# Redirect non www to www including https

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm having trouble redirecting:

`https://example.com` to `https://www.example.com`.

I've currently got this and its not achieving the result I need and I'm not sure why:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I basically want to redirect everything to `https://www.example.com`

I appreciate any help.

Comment: What result *is* it achieving?

Comment: @Ladadadada because there is no certificate for `https://example.com` you get an SSL warning, I was hoping the rewrite would overcome this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your comment you're trying to redirect in order to avoid a mis-matched URL SSL warning in the browser window.  This cannot be done, as the redirect happens after the SSL handshake (because it uses a `Location:` response header to a request that won't be sent until the SSL handshake occurs and is accepted by the user).

Your best approach is:

- Split example.com into a separate `VirtualHost` and use mod_alias as @HampusLi suggested
- Purchase another certificate for `example.com` and apply it to this `VirtualHost`

Alternatively, you could get a SAN (Subject Alternate Name) certificate that works for both `example.com` and `www.example.com`.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need mod_rewrite for this, you can use the much more lightweight built in module mod_alias with this simple syntax under the http vhost:

```
Redirect permanent / https://example.com/
```

Comment: Of course he means www.example.com